# How to pass value of variable from pug to php?

Tags: php, html, node.js, pug

How to pass variables from pug file to another php file? My nodejs server is running on port 8180 and xampp server on port 8080.

Comment: please show what you already tried and then show your problem

Answer (score 0):

Pug compile to html so pug works as a html. Thus just use it like html. Try form tag (with correct action attribute) or ajax with javascript.
But actually nodejs be able to do what php as well.